# Separate each row in a CSV

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I currently have a code that stores the entire database in a CSV. but I would like for each row to keep a CSV.
Is it possible to do this in PowerShell?
This is the code that I currently have:

```
$QUERY = "SELECT ID_ORDEN_COMPRA, COMPROBANTE_TRANSACCION FROM ORDEN_COMPRA WHERE  COMPROBANTE_TRANSACCION IS NOT NULL AND FECHA_PAGO_ORDEN_COMPRA <= '20180131 00:00:00'";    
Write-Output $QUERY;
#Invoke-Sqlcmd -AbortOnError  -EncryptConnection -ConnectionTimeout $TIMEOUT -Database 'dbprod_itswebpay' -ServerInstance $SQL_SERVER_FULLNAME_QA -Username "jobaccount" -Password "Jbct1947._" -Query $QUERY;
$DB_LIST = Invoke-Sqlcmd -AbortOnError -EncryptConnection -ConnectionTimeout $TIMEOUT -Database 'dbprod_itswebpay' -ServerInstance $SQL_SERVER_FULLNAME_SOURCE -Username $SQL_ACCOUNT_NAME_SOURCE -Password $SQL_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_SOURCE -Query $QUERY |
           Export-Csv -Path C:\test\test.csv -NoTypeInformation;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `ForEach-Object` loop to export each row individually:

```
$i = 1
Invoke-Sqlcmd ... | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Export-Csv "C:\test\${i}.csv" -NoType
    $i++
}
```

Comment: thank you, I worked
You already know how I can make the name of the file the same as it appears in "SELECT ID_ORDEN_COMPRA

Comment: `$_.ID_ORDEN_COMPRA`?

Comment: no, the name of the file remains with the information that has ID_ORDEN_COMPRA

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that. Please post a new question with a comprehensible problem description.